# Why activity indicator takes nearly 3 seconds to start when I click button

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, viewmodel, activity-indicator

I have `ActivityIndicator` in separate xaml file. Which I am using in MainPage xaml as CustomLoader. This CustomLoader visibility is being controlled by `bool` variable `VisibleLoader`

```
<custom:CustomLoader IsVisible="{Binding VisibleLoader}" 
           AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.5,1,1" 
           AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" Grid.Row="2">
</custom:CustomLoader>
```

In `MainPageViewModel` when I am clicking button stating `ActivityIndicator` it is taking time to start. See code below

`MainPageViewModel` code

```
private bool _visibleLoader = false;
public MainPageViewModel()
{
    VisibleLoader = true;
    current = this;
    GetAllProducts();
    SyncCommand = new Command(SyncDevice);
}

public bool VisibleLoader
{
    get
    {
        return _visibleLoader;
    }
    set
    {
        this._visibleLoader = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("VisibleLoader");
    }
}
```

Button click event code

```
public async void SyncDevice()
{
    try
    {
        VisibleLoader = true;
        IsBusy = true;
        PageMessage = string.Empty;
        var strSerialNumber = DependencyService.Get<IDataHelper>().GetIdentifier();
        //VisibleButtons = true;
        resourceService = new ResourceService(new RequestProvider());
        if (GlobalSettings.deviceId == 0)
        {
            DeviceDetails deviceDtls = await resourceService.GetDeviceDetails(strSerialNumber);
            GlobalSettings.deviceId = deviceDtls.Id.Value;
        }
        if (GlobalSettings.deviceId.ToString() != null)
        {
            DevicesList data = await resourceService.GetProducts(GlobalSettings.deviceId);
            //this.lstProducts = data.Devices[0].Products;
            this.lstProducts = data != null ? data.Devices[0].Products : null;
            if (lstProducts != null && lstProducts.Count != 0)
            {
                //Filter Products from Parameter file
                var filterProducts = GlobalSettings.GetFilterProducts();
                if (filterProducts.Count > 0)
                {
                    //lstProducts = lstProducts.Where(product => !filterProducts.Any(fp => product.Name.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(fp.ToLowerInvariant()))).ToList();
                    lstProducts = lstProducts.Where(product => filterProducts.Any(fp => product.Name.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(fp.ToLowerInvariant()))).ToList();
                }
                TotalProducts = lstProducts.Count;
                lstProducts = lstProducts.OrderBy(s => s.Order).ThenBy(s => s.Name).ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                PageMessage = "No products found.";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            PageMessage = "Error occured. Please try again later.!";
        }
        NotifyPropertyChanged("lstProducts");
        resourceService = new ResourceService(new RequestProvider());
        await resourceService.SyncDevice(GlobalSettings.deviceId);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        VisibleLoader = false;
    }
    VisibleLoader = false;
    IsBusy = false;
}
}
```

Button in xaml file

```
 <Button Text="Sync device" Command="{Binding SyncCommand}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    BackgroundColor="LightBlue"  Margin="5" TextColor="White" BorderRadius="10" HeightRequest="40"></Button>
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: ActivityIndicator will be visible when the main thread is blocked e.g. when you execute some async/await Task.
If it's possible, try to re-work your SyncDevice method in a way that you use it as async Task.

Comment: I am not getting your point. Thank you.

Comment: Just like in the answer below from @G.hakim, you have to either change your void to Task or to restructure your calls in a way so that the boolean is immediately changed. So maybe setting VisibleLoader = true somewhere else, before you call SyncDevice().

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all if your sync device method is not an event I would suggest you make it a task instead since async voids are not a good practice.

```
public async Task SyncDevice()
```

Also, it could be that your boolean in not changing in the main thread which is, in turn, causing this situation so try something like

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(()=>{ //Change visibility... });
```

Make sure that you only add relevant code in here because this blocks the main thread, in turn, makes the UI freeze

### Update

Then your command would look something like:

```
new Command(async ()=>{await SyncDevice()});
```

Comment: It is really not making any difference. I can't change void to Task, getting error 'wrong return type'.

Comment: Can you share more code because I do not think this should be the case?

Comment: I have added a fix take a look!